# Hector SLAM map does not update based on robot motion

Tags: slam, ros-kinetic, hector, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am having trouble with Hector SLAM using a car with LIDAR and no odometry frame. I started with a recorded bag file that has Velodyne LIDAR data and used rosrun pointcloud_to_laserscan pointcloud_to_laserscan_node to convert from pointcloud2 format to scan format. Now I am trying to run Hector SLAM, without using odometry frame. I am following the information on this page http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot, part 2, “Use without odom frame.”

I am able to generate a map, but the map just expands radially from the center. My car is definitely driving, but the map looks like the car is sitting in the same spot.

I suspect that there is something wrong with the transformations between the car and the earth. I tried using tf_echo to look at the transform between the robot and the earth, but the values there don’t seem to make sense and the transform seems to always be the same, because the car isn’t always driving at a constant speed.

Here is the launch file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ekahpEBisAF5I0TgFsz1nHTVONa7A0J/view?usp=sharing

Here is the bag file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RInfiRPoOjXgsyuL3lbHorSmNWwlg7df/view?usp=sharing

Here is a picture of the tf tree: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nZmaHNeuY9J1W3CDKB22xJzhrb4XMP3Q/view?usp=sharing

Here is the corresponding camera image video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e89P7bOvhymCf7b3ivObNdlGvgrEqv0Z/view?usp=sharing

Here is the current map in rviz: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zbHZd3N4rkgxVAqFNkMjMgLKCbuVHdVk/view?usp=sharing

I am using ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04 dual-booted on a Dell Inspiron computer.

What am I doing wrong that makes the map appear to not move?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321541/hector-slam-map-does-not-update-based-on-robot-motion/) by [danielwu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40970/danielwu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@danielwu, can you try to add

```
<param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
```

to your launch file.
Then,  play your rosbag file

```
 rosbag play --clock newVelo.bag
```

---

Originally posted by [samialperen](https://answers.ros.org/users/39086/samialperen/) with karma: 70 on 2019-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0